# Inserting "holes" on a graph.

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, wolfram-alpha

I am trying to plot the set  $A = \big\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid x^{2} + y^{2} < 2 \big\} - \big\{(0,\frac{1}{n}) \mid n=1,2,3 \dots \big\}$.  I have tried different combinations of set difference on wolframalpha but can't get it to pick up anything but the disk.  Also, maybe there is a better way using Matlab if someone can recommend a method.

Comment: One of the sets is discrete while the other isn't - so in some true sense, that set looks like a disk and is being drawn accurately; you'd probably be better off drawing the disk and then plotting the points removed.

Comment: Good point.  I can just plot circles as points on Matlab.  Thanks.